# Android - Exceptions while sending post request to the server

Tags: java, android, json, post, request

In my android project I have a class for the HTTP requests to my server. There I have methods for sendGet, sendPost and sendPut. Here is the code for the sendPost method:

```
public JSONObject sendPost(String urlString, String urlParameters) {

        URL url;
        JSONObject jObj = null;
        String json = "";

        try{

            url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line+"\n");
            }
            br.close();

            json = sb.toString();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try{
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        }
        catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(jObj);

        return jObj;

    }
```

It should return the server response as a JSONObject. If I send a post to my server, I get the following exceptions:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://...` (In the line where I create the BufferedReader)

`org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of` (In the line where I do jObj = new JSONObject(json);)

But if I copy the url to my browser there are no problems with it. And it seems like everything is working, because my server has received and processed the request. But why I get these errors and an empty JSONObject as result?

**EDIT:**

On my node.js server I send responses in the following format:

`res.status(200).json({ success: "true" });`

or

`res.status(400).json({ success: "false", message:"..." });`

**EDIT 2:**

After @greenapps comment I changed my code a bit:

```
    ...
    json = sb.toString();
    jObj = new JSONObject(json);

    br.close();
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

} catch (MalformedURLException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (JSONException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return jObj;
```

Now the JSONException is gone, but the FileNotFoundException is still there and the jObj is still empty when it got returned.

Comment: `wr.close();` Do not close the stream as it might end the connection too.

Answer (score 0):

I had a bug in my node.js server and the response code of the server was 502. And the BufferedReader only works with a 200 status code. Thats why I got the exceptions. Now I have a if around the BufferedReader:

```
if(connection.getResponseCode() == 200) {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }

    json = sb.toString();
    jObj = new JSONObject(json);

    br.close();
}else{
    json = "{ success: \"false\" }";
    jObj = new JSONObject(json);
}
```